# Can I increase the default font size for the Notes in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, notes.app

Can I increase the default font size for the Notes in Mountain Lion?

The text is too small, I would like to see big characters when I create a new note instead.

UPDATE:

```
<dict>
        <key>FontName</key>
        <string>Noteworthy-Light</string>
        <key>Size</key>
        <integer>20</integer>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go in "Terminal.app" and write (if your system is in english):

nano /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/DefaultFonts.plist

You will see a long file, but it's easy to understand it's content. You just need to change the ?? value, it is the default font size for each font.

When you are done, just <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save then <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close.

Restart Notes, select your default font and your font should follow the new default

Comment: I've done as you say (see my updated question: now fonts have value = 20), however the fonts are not updated in Notes (I've restarted Notes app)

Comment: After restarted Notes, you need to select again your default font so that the changes will take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go in Format -> Font -> Bigger or use Command+ to boost font size

Comment: That only works if I select some text. I need to set the **default** font size for all notes..

Comment: There don't seem to be a way to set defaults, there is not even a Preferences menu or anything. With the keyboard shortcut, it's less of a pain.

Comment: The thing is that I get the notes from the iPhone with iCloud and they are a bit hard to read on mac.