# Can you increase the font size in Reminders?

Tags: reminders

The Reminders app in OSX Mountain Lion has no preferences, so I'm wondering if there is any "under the hood" way to increase the font size.  It's too small for use on high res displays.

Comment: I am assuming that you are referring to Reminders on Mac OSX and *not* iOS?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question to reflect this fact.

Comment: Did you solve??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There may be a way to hack the app, but I haven't come across it yet. The font is too small for me to use comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

if there is a hack it is probably related to this one:

[Can I increase the default font size for the Notes in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57728/can-i-increase-the-default-font-size-for-the-notes-in-mountain-lion)

then all we need to do is find out the font name

Comment: I poked around myself after seeing the Notes hack, but it wasn't directly applicable to Reminders.